# ReactJS web push notification at a certain time?

Tags: reactjs, push-notification

I'm trying to build a web application based on React.JS (not React-Native) and Django for its backend. I'm struggling right now on how to send push notifications on a specific time. Are there any useful modules/APIs that can support time based push notifications?

To be exact... even if I exit the website, as long as my browser (ex: Chrome) is on, I want to still be able to get a notification at the time I set.

Comment: Not sure of the specifics for Django but https://rossta.net/blog/web-push-notifications-from-rails.html has instructions for Rails, which should contain the ideas needed to send notifications to the user. You could queue the notification on a background job to run a specific time.

Comment: How about using cron-jobs in your server to run a command every minute that checks the time and uses `pusher` or `socket.io` to fire a notification to your clients?

Comment: That sounds actually pretty plausible. What are pushers though? I've never heard of them. Can you provide a link?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly the Front end framework is not much relevant , secondly you could use firebase push notification , generate a client side token for that browser and send it to your DB and store it, then you can use something like `django-cronjobs` and time it when you want a push say at 5 pm UTC on every day , set it there and in that you can use fcm to push notification to it.
Ref [this github repo for fcm django](https://github.com/xtrinch/fcm-django) you just need to put django-cronjob code to trigger that file.